# Django отправка взаимосвязанных форм

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, веб-программирование

В моем тренировочном проекте на django есть страница с следующим сценарием:
Форма для добавления типа изделия (модель Type_of_product, поля формы model, department_id), плюс кнопка, которая добавляет произвольное количество форм для описания возможных характеристик изделия(модель Characteristic_of_product, поля формы label, units, description).

Предполагается, что при нажатии "Сохранить", в модели Type_of_product создается запись, и на основе ее ключа произвольное количество записей в Characteristic_of_product

Модели:

```
class Type_of_product(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department_id = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Characteristic_of_product(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type_of_product_id = models.ForeignKey('Type_of_product', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    units = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Вьюшки:

```
def type_product_add_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TypeProductAdd(request.POST)
        department_id_v = request.POST.get("department")
        if form.is_valid():
            add_type = Type_of_product.objects.create(model=form.cleaned_data['label'],
                                                      department_id_id=department_id_v)
            add_type.save()
            request.session['Type_of_product_id'] = add_type.id
    else:
        form = TypeProductAdd()
    return render(request, 'type_product_add_from.html', {'form': form})


def characteristics_of_product_add_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CharacteristicAdd(request.POST)
        type_of_product_id = request.session.get("Type_of_product_id")
        if form.is_valid():
            add_char = Characteristic_of_product.objects.create(label=form.cleaned_data['label'], type_of_product_id_id=type_of_product_id, units=form.cleaned_data['units'], description=form.cleaned_data['description'])
            add_char.save()
            return redirect(type_product_add_form)
    else:
        form = CharacteristicAdd()
    return render(request, 'characteristics_of_product_add_form.html', {'form': form})
```

код страницы добавления изделия:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Форма добавления нового типа изделия</h1>
    <form id="type_product_add" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form }}
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="content"></div>
        <input class="btn btn-default" id="btn_add" type="button" value="Добавить характеристику">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#btn_add').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "char/",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#content").append(html);
                    }
                });
            });
            $('#btn_submit').click(function(){
                 var type_product = document.getElementById('type_product_add');
                 var content = document.getElementById('content');
                 var elements = content.querySelectorAll('form');
                 type_product.submit();
                 console.log(type_product);
                   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                       var f = elements[i];
                       f.submit();
                       console.log(f);
                   }
            });
         });
    </script>
        <input id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
{% endblock %}
```

код формы характеристики:

```html
    <form action="{% url 'characteristics_of_product_add_form' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form }}
        </table>
    </form>
```

Данное исполнение приводит к тому, что формы обрабатываются в неправильном порядке и по этому страница либо вылетает с ошибкой либо записывает ID типа изделия от предыдущей сессии.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить обрабатываться формы в нужном мне порядке. Подозреваю кейс довольно стандартный, но к сожалению это ближайшее решения, которое я смог реализовать. Возможно есть принципиально другое решения задачи.

Comment: Вам нужен formset.

Comment: Большое спасибо, не знаю как 3 дня гугления меня не привели к formset, а увели в сторону js, но теперь все работает как надо